# Java : Split Date by n parts

Tags: java, date

I have two `Date` values in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` format.

And i have a dynamic int variable which will be updated by another process.

(e.g)

```
Date start = new Date(<some long value>); //2020-01-01 11:12:13.111
Date end = new Date(<some long value>); //2020-01-10 14:15:16.222

int count = 5; //this is dynamic
```

Then i need an list of `Date` between `start` and `end` divided in to 5 parts.

```
In simple words (example):

start = 1PM;
end = 5PM;

count = 5;

list = (1PM, 2PM, 3PM, 4PM, 5PM)
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: "parts" is not very descriptive, what does it imply? In your example it would seem it means hours, but is that always the case? It may be you just need to rephrase your question to say you want the number of hours between two dates?

Comment: You seem to be starting with two `long` values. Do you know how to find the difference between them and divide it by 5?

Comment: Please provide your sample code that you have tried but could not succeed.

Comment: **Don't use `Date`.** Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: Like @MCEmperor I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use for example `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

In the case of `count` equal to 5, I understand that you want 5 times, so 4 equally long intervals between them.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Tirane");
    
    ZonedDateTime start = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_577_873_533_111L).atZone(zone);
    ZonedDateTime end = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_578_662_116_222L).atZone(zone);
    int count = 5;
    
    Duration total = Duration.between(start, end);
    Duration each = total.dividedBy(count - 1);
    
    ZonedDateTime current = start;
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(current);
        current = current.plus(each);
    }
    System.out.println(end);
```

Output from this example snippet is:

> ```
> 2020-01-01T11:12:13.111+01:00[Europe/Tirane]
> 2020-01-03T17:57:58.888750+01:00[Europe/Tirane]
> 2020-01-06T00:43:44.666500+01:00[Europe/Tirane]
> 2020-01-08T07:29:30.444250+01:00[Europe/Tirane]
> 2020-01-10T14:15:16.222+01:00[Europe/Tirane]
> ```

Please substitute your desired time zone if it didn’t happen to be Europe/Tirane. Use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` if you want the default time zone of your JVM.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Nice answer. Just one suggestion: the last 6 lines can be made shorter and lucid by writing them as `for (ZonedDateTime current = start; current
    .isBefore(end.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)); current = current.plus(each))
   System.out.println(current);`

Comment: I do not understand why people have downvoted the question. I do not see any problem with the question and I was able to understand the requirement in the first read. I've upvoted the question as well.

Comment: I too find the question perfectly clear. Downvotes might have been because of lack of shown effort on the questioner’s part. I agree that it’s OK in this case. Minimal examples are often good, but not all questions need them.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash In the case of `(1PM, 2PM, 3PM, 4PM, 5PM)`, `end.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)` will not give the correct result. One might try `end.plus(count, ChronoUnit.NANOS)`, but that gets cryptic. While I see that my code isn’t perfectly lucid, I find it safest to keep it as it is.

Comment: Got it...yes, now it makes more sense to me to keep it in its current form.